# share a folder on freenas with linux as wel as windows clients

Tags: samba, nfs, file-sharing, truenas

we have a freenas as a file server.
how can i share a single folder with both windows and linux clients.?

Answer (score 1):

Share the folder as SMB. Your windows clients can mount this natively. You can then use cifs on your linux clients to mount the smb shares e.g.

```
mkdir /path_to/mount
mount -t cifs -o guest //server/share /path_to/mount
```

Have a look at the [**mount**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) and [**mount.cifs**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) man pages for the details

Comment: i have read that accessing files this way causes causes file corruption.and will this cause access right issues?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply activate both NFS (for Linux) and Samba (for Windows) services. Then point both to the same directory. For me that has worked quite well, but I am not constantly accessing with a lot of clients, leave alone have concurrent write transactions. I am not sure if FreeNAS would handle those well with both services on the same folder.